# iOS Views return to original locations when textView becomesFirstResponder

Tags: ios, keyboard

Hello and thank you in advance...

I am moving views frame location in animation blocks.  After I move views, I am tapping a textView to allow for editing/input.  When the textView is tapped, the views I moved previously pop back to their original (unmoved) frame locations.

I'm not sure what I am doing incorrectly here.

**THIS IS HOW I SETUP THE DIFFERENT FRAME POSITIONS TO ANIMATE TO**

```
    //Books active and rest position will effect other elements (paper and paperTextView)
self.bookRestPosition = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width * 0.10), (self.view.frame.size.height * 0.4), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
self.bookActivePosition = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y +100, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
self.bookOpenPosition = CGRectMake(self.bookActivePosition.origin.x, self.bookActivePosition.origin.y, 20, self.bookActivePosition.size.height);


self.quillRestPosition = self.quill.frame;
self.quillActivePosition = CGRectMake(self.quill.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y -200, self.quill.frame.size.width, self.quill.frame.size.height);

self.woodTableRestPosition = self.view.frame;
self.woodTableActivePosition = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y -200, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height +200);


self.paperRestPosition = self.bookRestPosition;
self.paperActivePosition = CGRectMake(self.bookOpenPosition.size.width,     self.bookActivePosition.origin.y, self.bookActivePosition.size.width, self.bookActivePosition.size.height);

self.paperTextViewRestPosition = self.bookRestPosition;
self.paperTextViewActivePosition = self.paperActivePosition;
self.paperTextView.editable = NO;


self.paper.alpha = 0.0;
self.paperTextView.alpha = 0.0;

self.paper.frame = self.bookRestPosition;
self.paperTextView.frame = self.bookRestPosition;
```

**THIS IS HOW I ANIMATE THEM**

```
- (IBAction)onBookTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
if (self.logCover.frame.origin.x == self.bookRestPosition.origin.x) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         [self activateLogAndViewsAssociated];
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         NSLog(@"Book Slid up!");
                     }];
}
else if (self.logCover.frame.origin.x == 0){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         [self everythingAtRestPosition];
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         NSLog(@"Book Slid Down!");
                     }];
}
}

- (IBAction)swipeBookLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
//if (self.logCoverImage.frame.origin.x == 0) {
    self.paper.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         [self.logCover     setFrame:self.bookOpenPosition];
                         self.editButton.alpha = 1.0;
                         self.editButton.enabled = YES;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         NSLog(@"Book Has Opened!");

                             //This must be here.  The paperTextView is     what the swipe right gesture is attached to
                         self.paperTextView.alpha = 1.0;
//                             self.logCoverImage.alpha = 0.0;
//                             self.quill.alpha = 0.0;
                     }];
//}
}
- (IBAction)onPaperSwipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     [self.logCover setFrame:self.bookActivePosition];
                     self.editButton.alpha = 0.0;
                     self.editButton.enabled = NO;
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     NSLog(@"Book Has Closed!");
                     //self.paper.alpha = 0.0;

//                         [NSUserDefaults *log = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//                         [log setObject:self.paperTextView     forKey:@"textLog"];

                 }];
}
- (IBAction)onBookSwipeDown:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
if (self.logCover.frame.origin.x == 0) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         [self everythingAtRestPosition];
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         NSLog(@"Book Slid Down!");
                     }];
}
}
- (IBAction)onBookSwipeUp:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (self.logCover.frame.origin.x == self.bookRestPosition.origin.x) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         [self activateLogAndViewsAssociated];
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         NSLog(@"Book Slid up!");
                     }];
}
}

- (void)animateAtStartup
{
self.logCover.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width,     self.view.frame.size.height, self.bookRestPosition.size.width,     self.bookRestPosition.size.height);
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     [self.logCover setFrame:self.bookRestPosition];
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     NSLog(@"Book Slid Down!");
                 }];
}
```

**AND THIS IS WHAT HAPPENS WHEN THE EDIT BUTTON IS PRESSED**

```
- (IBAction)onEditButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
self.paperTextView.editable = YES;
[self.paperTextView becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: This is because of auto layout. You should not set any frames when using auto layout. If you do, the views revert to the positions determined by their constraints whenever the view needs to relayout.

Comment: Awesome!  Ok that totally makes sense.  I just didn't know the rules.  So instead of animating the change of frame.  How would you suggest I move my views so they do not "relayout" to their original positions?

Comment: You make IBOutlets to any constraints that need to be modified, and change their "constant" value in code.

Comment: I have the same issue, how can I remove the auto layout?